# Combined probability involving $^n C _r$

Tags: probability

The discrete random variable $N$ takes positive integer values and has distribution given by

$\mathbf{P}(N=n)= \frac{1}{a} (\frac{a}{a+1})^n$ , $n\ge 1$

a is a positive constant.

A fair die is thrown a random number $N$ times. Let $X$denote the number of sixes obtained.

Given that $a=3$, Calculate $\mathbf{P}(N=4|X=3)$

$\mathbf{P}(X=3) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \mathbf{P}(X=3|N=n)$

$ = \sum^\infty_{n=0} [\frac{1}{3}(\frac{3}{4})^n][^nC_3(\frac{1}{6})(\frac{5}{6})^{n-3}]$

$= (\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{6})^3 (\frac{6}{5})^3 \sum^\infty_{n=0}$ $ ^n C_3 (\frac{5}{8})^n$

I get to be stuck next.